# How do I include a component in dynamically generated HTML string applied through [innerHTML] in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, angular-dynamic-components

So I want to add a component inside of some HTML that has been inserted into the DOM through [innerHTML]. My current approach is as follows, but I am stuck at trying to obtain an ElementRef...

I am dynamically generating a string of text and HTML and inserting it into an element as such:

```html
<p [innerHTML]='formattedHTML'></p>
```

`formattedHTML` is dynamic content, and will contain something like the following:

```html
Please welcome <span class="insert-name-component" data-user="{user_id: 'xxxxx', full_name: 'Test User'}"></span> to the company!
```

I already have a component, let's call it `<name>` (it takes `user_id` and `full_name` as inputs) that I want to insert into all instances of the `.insert-name-component` span. From here I was trying to apply a directive to the outer `<p>` element that somehow targets the span and inserts the `name` component into the span using ComponentFactory, but I did not know how to obtain an ElementRef of the span because it is added through [innerHTML]. Obviously I cannot use a #ref because it is not a template.

Is this possible? Or is there a different approach for adding a component to dynamic HTML like this?

Comment: Did you have to follow the `[innerHTML]` approach because you are tied to certain conditions? If this is not the case please share some more code in order to suggest a suitable solution for you.

Comment: How is the dynamically generated content created? Have you looked at using content projection?

Comment: @cybering I need to treat the value I am passing to innerHTML as having unknown content, I cannot think of a way I would make a component for it, if that is what you were thinking.

Comment: I understand but I am asking since you could achieve this kind of stuff using `<ng-content>` or  passing a `TemplateRef` to render in `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template`>